# Filtering array element using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have this JSON

```
products: [{
    id: "1",
    model: "123",
    price: "123",
    spec: "213",
    image: "",
    brand: "213",
    category: "1",
    sub_category: "1",
    color: "1",
    size: "1",
    order: "1",
    attributes: [{
        id: "1",
        attribute_id: "1",
        product_id: "1"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        attribute_id: "2",
        product_id: "1"
    }]
}, {
    id: "2",
    model: "456",
    price: "123",
    spec: "213",
    image: "",
    brand: "213",
    category: "1",
    sub_category: "1",
    color: "1",
    size: "1",
    order: "1",
    attributes: []
}]
```

I am trying to filter the products using ng-repeat

so my ng-repeat is :

```
<div ng-repeat="product in tv_selections.products | filter: {attributes[0].attribute_id:attribute} | filter:{size:size} | filter:{attribute2:attribute2}" >
```

I get the selected size and attributes from the controller and its correct

I know my attribute is wrong, but I dont know how I am going to do it, for the other filters its working, on the attributes is not

Comment: creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating your issue would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the documentation on **filters in angular** that is on

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

where this code is given ,

```
    Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
    <table id="searchTextResults">
      <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
        <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Angular does on its own, using **searchText** as reference it will put filter on each property inside the friend object.

Executable code check on this link :
 http://plnkr.co/edit/MEAHFagGSANOENsaldCC?p=preview

Likewise will be done for your code to search products,
check this out , a plunker is created for your answer :

http://plnkr.co/edit/PcF8hfr1ch8BNn2YpxDp?p=preview